# Excel: Extract Numbers from Date Strings

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have several malformed date columns.  I am trying to transform these columns into "month", "year", and "start_day" columns.

Here is an example sample:

```
January 13th, 2018
January 13th-14th 2018
January 5th-7th 2018
January 4th-8th 2018
December 9th-10th 2017
December 2nd-3rd 2017
December 2nd, 2017
December 2nd-3rd 2017
November 18th, 2017
November 18th-20th, 2017
November 17th-19th 2017
November 11th, 2017
November 11th-12th, 2017
November 11th-12th 2017
```

Note that sometimes there is a comma between the day abbreviation and the year, other times not.  My desired output (for the day column) would be:

```
13
13
5
4
9
2
2
2
18
18
17
11
11
11
```

I am not concerned about the second date (to the right of the hyphen).  I was able to get the month with `LEFT(A1, 3)` and the year with `RIGHT(A1, 4)`.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab the first numerical value to the right of the month without resorting to regex.  Any ideas?

Comment: You've tagged [vba]. Can you clarify if you want a code solution or a formula solution?

Comment: split on the space then check if the second character in the second result is a number or not and return either the first or the first two depending on the result.

Comment: @deanOC either works, but formula is preferred if possible.

Comment: @ScottCraner Or even (if using VBA) just use `Val` on the first two characters after the space (it will ignore the non-numeric character if it exists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2,1)),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,1))*1
```

Comment: a slightly shorter version: `=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2,1)),2,1))`

Comment: Wow.  Incredible work, both of you guys.  Excel Wizards.  Thanks

Comment: @Salek the number could be either 1 or 2 digits,  so for example `January 5th-7th 2018` would return `5t` and not `5`

Answer (score 2):

A VBA solution might be:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s() As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 14
        'Split text based on spaces
        s = Split(Cells(i, "A").Text)
        'Join bits together and convert to date
        'Val(Left(s(1), 2)) gives the day portion
        'Month and Year are directly from the source
        Cells(i, "B").Value = CDate(Val(Left(s(1), 2)) & " " & s(0) & " " & s(2))
    Next
End Sub
```

(Assumes data in A1:A14, and puts results in B1:B14)

Comment: This is also great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution:

```
=LOOKUP(99,--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,{1,2}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,{1,2}),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula that could take care of this;

```
=DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4)),VLOOKUP(MID(A1,1,3),$G$1:$H$12,2),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,(FIND("t",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1)))
```

This also assumes that there is a lookup table that has JAN, FEB, etc... with the number of the month.  That table needs to be sorted alphabetically by the month.  It should look like this;
APR 4
AUG 8
DEC 12
FEB 2
JAN 1
JUL 7
JUN 6
MAR 3
MAY 5
NOV 11
OCT 10
SEP 9

Also, you will have to do a search and replace the 'nd' with 'th' to avoid having to add a bunch of extra conditional code here.

I would also suggest that a second column of dates be added that would be populated by the 'to' dates that may appear.

Hope that helps.

Greg