# Extracting digits from strings in excel with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say we have strings like this and want to output digits out from it. The digits is not always in the beginning so I think I need to define condition as well.

Tried this [Excel: Extract Numbers from Date Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288928/excel-extract-numbers-from-date-strings/48289013)
but not working

[image]

how can we extract the digits from this kind of string in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats, today is the day you are going to add some [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) knowledge to your arsenal. This is how the result would look, if you add a vba formula to it:

[image]

In order to add the formula, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and paste the following code either in `Modul1` or in the `Worksheet`:

```
Public Function ExtractString(myRange As Range) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    Dim currentString As String
    Dim okIndex As Long

    okIndex = 1
    result = ""

    For i = 1 To Len(myRange.Text)
        currentString = Mid(myRange.Text, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(currentString) And okIndex >= 1 Then
            result = result & currentString
            okIndex = okIndex + 1
        Else
            If okIndex > 1 Then okIndex = -1
        End If
    Next

    ExtractString = result

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a formula solution, you can use:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))),1)
```

If you have O365 with the most recent updates, you can use:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))),1)
```

If you need to check for no-digits in the string, you can wrap the formula in `IFERROR`. eg:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))),1),"")
```

[image]